# doctrine search by array

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using symfony3 and I was wondering whether it is possible to search with doctrine and use a an array as parameters. here is my code:

```
foreach($statesData as $val){
            $dataState[] = array('id' => $val->getId());
        }
        $cities=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cities')->findByStateId($dataState);
```

I basically want the equivalent to 'LIKE' mysql expression

Comment: have you try it ? any erros ? because it should work like this

Comment: I get this error: "Notice: Array to string conversion"  at C:\\wamp\\www\\kleeked\\vendor\\doctrine\\orm\\lib\\Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Expr.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `IN` rather than `LIKE` - you can use the query builder to do that - something like this...

```
$cities=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cities');
$qb=$cities->createQueryBuilder('c');

$qb->where($qb->expr()->in('c.stateId', $dataState));
$query=$qb->query();

$result=$query->getResult();
```